# How long does it take to publish in a magazine?

Tags: publishing, academic-writing, timelines

How long does it take to publish in a magazine? I have had a piece under consideration—with a fair number of emails and discussions with the editor—for five months with the editor still on the fence about accepting it. I am planning to re-inquire about its status (it's been a month since the last one). Is this an exceptionally long time for a magazine submission?

For additional context, the magazine is semi-academic in nature. It is a theological publication and very much so not peer-reviewed, though the editorial board does take an active interest in making sure it's "up to snuff," which my paper had gone through in October.

A Post Script:
Thank you everyone! Based on what you've said, I decided to reach back out to the editor. He decided to come back with a rejection, though he has given me useful feedback over this whole 5 month process. Unfortunate, but not fruitless. Either way, a good learning experience. Thank you, again!

Comment: You tagged this [scientific-publishing]. Is it peer reviewed? What subject? Can you give any more details as to what type of publication it is?

Comment: It is a magazine, semi-academic in nature. It is a theological publications and very much so not peer-reviewed, though the editorial board does take an active interest in making sure its "up to snuff," which my paper had gone through in October. I tagged it "scientific-publication" due to the semi-academic nature.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Based on what you've said, I decided to reach back out to the editor. He decided to come back with a rejection, though he has given me useful feedback over this whole 5 month process. Unfortunate, but not fruitless. Either way, a good learning experience. Thank you, again!

Answer (score 0):

The turnaround times in scientific journals are about 2 months on average and usually no longer than 3 months. Often, the first review is followed by a revision of the article that the editors or reviewers have suggested, so that the overall time between first submission and final publication can take up to around a year.

Tournaround times for non-scholarly magazines vary widely between a few weeks and more than a year.

Commonly it should be communicated to you how long the respective steps in the decision making and publication process will take, or at least what the next step will be (so you can make an educated guess). In the absence of such communication it is impossible to know how long this individual editor will need to come to a conclusion about your submission, especially since you didn't disclose the name of the magazine and the circumstances of the indecision.

You may inquire. And you should be free to withdraw your submission if you prefer not to wait and submit elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure to what extent your answer applies since it's neither a "scholarly journal" nor a "scientific journal" because there's no peer review—only a review by the editor that OP said they already got through.

Comment: @Laurel Edited.

Comment: Gotcha. A pretty high variance, then. I suppose we should all be grateful that publishing is relatively unregulated, but it does seem to leave one in limbo! The reason I'm not mentioning the magazine is because its sufficiently well known in the USA that I'd not want the magazine's staff to stumble into me asking questions which could be construed as bothersome to them. But this does let me know that I'm less likely to be in a "run around" situation with them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at 2 major Christian magazines, they have quite a detailed guideline including the vetting process they do: [*Christianity Today*](https://help.christianitytoday.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047411253-How-do-I-write-for-CT-) says 3 weeks (with special consideration for author-imposed deadline), [*First Things*](https://www.firstthings.com/submissions) says 4 weeks (with invitation to send a follow-up query).

Another idea is to ask well-published authors who have previously published to various theological journals and magazines such as theology professor Roger Olson (his publication list [here](https://www.patheos.com/blogs/rogereolson/my-articles-etc/)) who also maintains [a blog](https://www.patheos.com/blogs/rogereolson/) where he is *very responsive* to comments.

Comment: That is a much quicker turn-around! That encourages me to reach back out--I might need to get over my feeling of worry over bothering the editor. I might reach out to some people to inquire, like you've also recommended. Thank you very much!

Comment: @David_Ave If you could find a similar page about their process on their magazine's website, then you have something to go on.

Comment: In my experience (not Christian magazines) the delays are extremely variable from one magazine to the next; in particular it depends on how many piece submissions they get and how many pieces they need. Even if your piece is high quality enough to be accepted in the end, you're going to remain much longer in the queue if they already have enough pieces for their next five issues, than if they're missing a piece for their next issue.

Comment: They had no such page even though they're an established magazine. Such is life. It seems to be as Stef here has said--looks like I was caught up in the random matter of publishing luck.

Answer (score 0):

It varies from 'zine to zine. The best way IMO is to look up a particular place up on the Grinder: thegrinder.diabolicalplots.com